# Passing String Litteral to Function that takes a pointer

Tags: c, string

If I have the function that takes a pointer to a string like this:

```
void outTxData(uint8_t *outString)
{
//Do something.

}
```

How do I pass a string literal to it? I.E. I want to just do.....

`outTxData("HELLO")` but I can't as the function takes a pointer. What's the easiest way to get around this?

I've tried all sorts to no avail.
I dont know how to make a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: `"HELLO"` decays to a pointer to it, but the type is `char *` (preferred would be `const char*`), not `uint8_t *`.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the string literal, e.g.

```
void outTxData(uint8_t *outString)
{
//Do something.

}

outTxData((uint8_t*) "HELLO);
```

or

```
void outTxData(char *outStringCharPointer)
{
uint8_t* outString = (uint8_t*) outStringCharPointer;
//Do something.
}

outTxData("HELLO");
```

Note that `char const *` or `uint8_t const *` is best, so that you don't accidentally cause UB by trying to modify the contents of the string literal.